Как запустить client и server приложение (Node.JS, бд: sqlite3)
Господа, здравствуйте. Вот уже несколько дней пытаюсь запустить сайт (server, client) на node.js + nginx. Сайт заказал у кодера, и кодер вроде скинул инструкцию (но она написана через жопу, и по итогу ничего не получается). Сам кодер пропал, поэтому не могу никак его запустить. Хз что здесь написать, чтобы вы помогли с решением.
Могу пока написать структуру файлов. Если нужны ещё какие-то скрины, то пишите... Скину монеточку тому кто поможет ... Реально надоело уже... ps: пытаюсь установить на убунтум



Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Ну инструкцию приложите что ли и что не выходит в итоге? Может ошибки какие?

@SwaD, вот что он писал - в папке с сервером написать след команда: npm i, npm run create-db, npm i -g pm2,  pm2 start npm -- start. В папке с клиентом написать: npm i, npm run build, а потом ещё раз написать pm2 start npm -- start (в папке с сервером).
Когда пишу последнюю команду вылетает ошибка: [PM2] [ERROR] Script not found /home/serv2/restoraunt-server/--
